# Python ebay sdk - how to add item specifics dynamically?

Tags: python, django, python-3.5, ebay-api

I am using [ebay-python-sdk](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python)
I created the myitem object, so I can `api.execute('VerifyAddItem', myitem)` it.
But I need to add ItemSpecifics, and here I encounter problems.
 I have an array of item specifics made of tuples:

```
a = [('Occasion', 'Casual'), ('Brand', 'Ralph Lauren'), ('Style', 'Polo Shirt')]
```

and i want to add it to 'myitem'.
so i use:

```
for p in a:
    ar.append([{"Name":p[0]}, {"Value":p[1]}])

myitem["Item"]["ItemSpecifics"]["NameValueList"] = ar
```

but i get error 'KeyError: 'ItemSpecifics''
What do I need to change in my code to add it correctly?

If I write this code to myitem object, it is ok. I just don't know how to add it dynamically.

```
"ItemSpecifics": {
                "NameValueList": [
                    {"Name": "Occasion", "Value": "Casual"},
                    {"Name": "Brand", "Value": "Ralph Lauren"},
                    {"Name": "Style", "Value": "Polo Shirt"},
                    {"Name": "Sleeve Style", "Value": "Short Sleeve"}
                ]
            },
```

myitem object:

```
myitem = {
        "Item": {
            "Title": name,
            "Description": "<![CDATA[{}]]>".format(desc),
            "PrimaryCategory": {"CategoryID": "176984"},
            "StartPrice": str(round(Decimal(start_price), 2)),
            "CategoryMappingAllowed": "true",
            "Country": "GB",
            "ConditionID": "1000",
            "Currency": "GBP",
            "DispatchTimeMax": "3",
            "ListingDuration": "{}".format(str(auction_len)),
            "ListingType": "FixedPriceItem",
            "PaymentMethods": "PayPal",
            "PayPalEmailAddress": "test@ebay.com",
            "PictureDetails": {"PictureURL": pict_list},
            "PostalCode": "bh102as",
            "ProductListingDetails":{
               "EAN": "8054241786423",
            },
            "Quantity": str(round(Decimal(qty), 0)),
            "ReturnPolicy": {
                "ReturnsAcceptedOption": "ReturnsAccepted",
                "RefundOption": "MoneyBack",
                "ReturnsWithinOption": "Days_30",
                "Description": "If you are not satisfied, return the book for refund.",
                "ShippingCostPaidByOption": "Buyer"
            },
            "ShippingDetails": [{
                "ShippingType": "Free",
                "ShippingServiceOptions": {
                    "FreeShipping": "true",
                    "ShippingServicePriority": "1",
                    "ShippingService": "ShippingMethodStandard",
                    "ShippingServiceCost": "0"
                }
            },
            {
                "ShippingType": "Flat",
                "ShippingServiceOptions": {
                    "FreeShipping": "false",
                    "ShippingServicePriority": "2",
                    "ShippingService": "UK_RoyalMailSecondClassStandard",
                    "ShippingServiceCost": "0.50"
                }
            }],
            "Site": "UK"
        }
    }
```

Can you point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please post your `myitem` object?

Comment: I have just updated my question and added myitem object

Comment: Well, you first have to set an object as value of the key `ItemSpecifics`, and then you can continue. That is, `myitem["Item"]["ItemSpecifics"]={}` and then `myitem["Item"]["ItemSpecifics"]["NameValueList"] = ar`

Comment: Excellent! Thank you, I would upvote your answer, but I dont know how to up vote a comment. However Thank you @Itay4! Still needed to change `ar.append([{"Name":p[0]}, {"Value":p[1]}])` to `ar.append([{"Name":p[0], "Value":p[1]}])` to make it work.

Comment: Glad I could help! You can upvote a comment if you click on the up arrow on the left of the comment when hover it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because using the `x[key] = val` syntax only works one level deep. Trying to assign `x[y][key] = val` results in an error because `y` doesn't exist within the dictionary. If you execute `myitem['Item']['ItemSpecifics']={}`, before trying to create a dictionary within it will work. Alternatively, you could specify it right away when you create you `dict`:

```
myitem = {
    "Item": {
        ...
        "ItemSpecifics": {}
    }
}
```